# Invoking a Stored procedure in spring boot application and assign the result to RowMapper

Tags: java, spring-boot, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which returns a List. I need to invoke it and assign the result to a model call.

Below is the Repository class i have written

```
@Repository
public class addRepository {

@Procedure(name = "up_Getdata(?)"
public List<String> fetchResult(@Param("inParam") String inParam){

}
```

My model class has 3 fields name,age,departName

Any help on how to map this will he helpful

Answer (score 1):

I think the best answer would be to simply follow [this tutorial on Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-stored-procedures), the **tl;dr** would be:

1. Create your entity class with the 3 fields.
2. Change the return type of `fetchResult()` to your newly created entity.
3. Change `addRepository` from a `class` to an `interface`
4. Be sure that you chose the correct procedure name, you can choose between one of the following ways

   - `@Procedure("up_Getdata")`
   - `@Procedure(procedureName = "up_Getdata")`
   - `@Procedure(value = "up_Getdata")`
   - I am not sure if `@Procedure(name = "up_Getdata)` would be valid

Comment: i would like to know how to map the result to a model using row mapper

Comment: @user9140475 when you use jpa with an entity, it will already map the row automatically

Comment: i don not have a entity here. That is why using a model. some sort of sample code will he helpfl

Comment: @user9140475 please take a look at the link in my answer, the blog post can explain it much better than I do

Comment: yeah.. but it is ot explainig how to map it to model class using RowMapper

Answer (score 0):

Another approach without `@Procedure` but works perfectly also in spring boot:

```
    @Repository
    public class YourRepository {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public List<YourModelClass> executeStoredProcedure(String inParam) {
        StoredProcedureQuery query = entityManager.createStoredProcedureQuery(
                "up_Getdata", YourMapper.MAPPING_NAME);

        query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("@inParam", String.class, ParameterMode.IN);
        query.setParameter("@inParam", inParam);

        return query.getResultList();
    }
}
```

Your Mapper:

```
@MappedSuperclass
@SqlResultSetMapping(name = YourMapper.MAPPING_NAME, classes = {
        @ConstructorResult(targetClass = YourModelClass.class, columns = { @ColumnResult(name = "name"),
                @ColumnResult(name = "age"), @ColumnResult(name = "departName") }) })
public abstract class YourMapper {
    public static final String MAPPING_NAME = "MappingName";
}
```

Comment: if you could suggest me how to do in repository with @Procedure would be helpful

Comment: I edited my answer. But no, I don't know how to use it with @Procedure.